# Factory for DAO in Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, generics, dao, factory-pattern

I'm struggling to create the following situation:

First, there are several Linq to SQL Table objects that do almost the same thing. Let's call them products_something, products_somethingElse, etc..

Second, there is an interface that does all the common methods of the Products DAO. Firstly i tried to create only one DAO for all products, since i could handle it's differences on another Layer (a DAL). But since Linq to SQL needs strongly typed references, i end up using one DAO for each type of products. I don't really know if it's possible to do what i mentioned before.

Last, i have a ProductsDaoFactory which instantiates the correct ProductDao based on client side (user view) choice. Since i don't know which type of product will be chosen at runtime, i created a generic factory to handle it.

Here's the code:

```
public enum ProductEnum
    {
        SimpleProduct, ComplexProduct, RevisedProduct, BrokenProduct
    }

    public interface IProducts<T>
    {
        T GetProductById(int id);
        IQueryable<T> GetAllProducts(string product_name, DateTime product_age);
        //Several other common methods
    }



public static class ProductFactory
    {
      //This won't compile because i have to set what's the type of the DAO i want
        public static IProducts<T> GetProductDAO(ProductEnum product)
        {
            switch (product)
            {
                case ProductEnum.SimpleProduct:
                    return new SimpleProductDAO();
                case ProductEnum.ComplexProduct:
                    return new ComplexProductDAO();
                case ProductEnum.RevisedProduct:
                    return new RevisedProductDAO();
                case ProductEnum.BrokenProduct:
                    return new BrokenProductDAO();
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public class SimpleProductDAO : IProducts<SimpleProductDAO>
    {

        public SimpleProductDAO GetProductById(int id)
        {
            //Implementation
        }

        public IQueryable<SimpleProductDAO> GetAllProducts(string product_name, DateTime product_age)
        {
            //Implementation
        }
    }
```

Problem is: I can't define the return type of the factory method because it's generic. I'd have to passe its type to the factory which would simply break the factory idea. **So, how can i create a factory method that instantiates generic types of an interface?**

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your generic is not really generic. So your methods should not be generic at all since I cannot say:

```
GetProductDAO<int>(someEnum);
```

I believe removing the generic from the factory will not only solve the problem but also provides better clarity and coherence for the users of the API. **Having said that, generics does allow for better intellisense.**

**My favourite solution** will be to remove the enum and just pass the generic type will you add a restriction on the method.

```
public static IProducts<T> GetProductDAO<T>() where T: ISomeMarkerInterface, new()
```

So `SimpleProductDAO` whill implement `ISomeMarkerInterface` which is just an empty interface:

```
public interface ISomeMarkerInterface
{

}
```

And factory gets small:

```
public static class ProductFactory
{
    public static IProducts<T> GetProductDAO<T>() where T : ISomeMarkerInterface, IProducts<T>, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

## Alternatively

Define the factory as this:

```
public static IProducts<T> GetProductDAO<T>(ProductEnum product)
{
    ...
```

This is not my favourite solution since it can be abused without a restriction

Comment: But defining as you suggested won't break the whole idea of a factory, since i'll have to know which kind of product to instantiate instead of letting the factory do it for me? From where do say to remove the generics? From the interface or from the factory?

Comment: Compiler is not recognizing the `where T: ISomeMarkerInterface, new()` for some reason. `SimpleProduct` is already implementing `ISomeMarkerInterface`. And another thing, declaring `where T: ISomerMarkerInterface, new` won't cause the activator slugginess problem?

Comment: @AdrianoRR try where T: new(), ISomeMarkerInterface

Comment: `new()` directive must be the last constraint. I believe it won't recognize because you have to define it like `GetProductDAO<T>`. However this cause a problem with `return new T();` since it needs a explicit conversion to `IProduct<T>`.

Comment: Forget what i said before. The problem is that i have to define on my factory what's the type of the product i want to be instantiated (at compiler time). I believe this breaks the idea of a factory.

Comment: @AdrianoRR what do you say that? we defined it as `public static IProducts<T> GetProductDAO<T>()` so returning `IProducts<T>`

Comment: Yep, after posting my comment i saw it was wrong :) srry about that. Anyway, by returning a new T as a member of IProducts<T> i still have to declare its type when calling GetProductDAO<T> haven't i? If that is the case why would i be needing a factory?